# How to save high resolution .png from Viewer in RStudio?

Tags: r, png, rstudio, viewer

Is there a function similar to `ggsave` for `ggplots` for saving high definition pictures from the viewer in RStudio?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you might directly use the available graphic devices and write your plot into a file, e.g., as follows (check `?device` for other file formats):

```
# specify the device / file format (and start device)
png(file = "myplot.png")
plot(1:2, 1:2, type = "l")
#turn off the device
dev.off()
```